# Issue in rendering items in the main thread from a worker thread

Tags: java, android, android-handler, ui-thread, android-runonuithread

I have created a counter app that counts from 0 to infinity until the loop is stopped using a stop button. The app contains 2 buttons(start and stop) and 1 textview.
I aim to display the values from 0 to infinity(until the loop is stopped) in the textview. I am using a while loop.

For example, the count value starts from 0 so the while loop starts from 0 and continues until the loop is terminated using the stop button. I want to display values in real time in the textview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean start;
    int count=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bt1=findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button bt2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
        TextView tv=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Handler h=new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
        

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                start=true;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while(start){
                                count=count+1;
                        }
                        h.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tv.setText(" "+count);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });
        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                start=false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code above is not displaying values in real-time in the textview. What's the issue? Also, should I use a handler or runonUIThread for such tasks?

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: so everytime the start button is pressed, a new thread will be created counting on a shared variable. this is an issue. however the main problem here the count operation will be so fast, the human eye cannot catch the numbers. You should use a time based event instead of using a while loop since this is not an embedded bare metal microcontroller app. You develop an app which will run on top of an operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `runOnUiThread`, since the `while` loop is blocking the UI thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tv.setText(" "+count);
    }
});
```

here's the refactored code to get this working.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean start;
    int count=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bt1=findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button bt2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
        TextView tv=findViewById(R.id.textView);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                start=true;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while(start){
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    tv.setText(" "+count);
                                }
                            });
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                start=false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The above code is displaying the values in real-time however it is crashing the application. Also, how is the while loop blocking the UI thread if I am using it in a new(worker) thread?

Comment: What's the crash log? 
You are running the `while` loop in the main thread which is also responsible for updating the `ui`, that's how its blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Crash log- Skipped 247 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
One big frame drop total:2771 frameGap:2780 delta#2744#22#3#17#0#4

Comment: I think the app is crashing due to the while loop. When I click on the start button, the value of the while loop increases rapidly. This might be the reason. The value reaches 50,000 in a matter of seconds. I think the main thread is unable to handle such big values. What do you think? Can I run the loop at a slow pace?

Comment: Well, I found the issue, it was the while loop which was causing the issue. I used Thread.sleep(1000) after count++ to solve the issue.